# HTML Bootstrap attribute required not working

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm using the vuexy admin panel in my laravel, i want use form validation, I need to add a css and js plugin. I've tried adding it but it doesn't appear  under textfield "This field must be filled" when submitting  where is the error in my code i add all plugin css and JS ?

Code header  CSS

```
    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/datatables.min.css')}}">
    <!-- END: Vendor CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/css/bootstrap.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/css/forms/select/select2.min.css')}}">

    <!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/css/plugins/forms/validation/form-validation.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('app-assets/sweetalert/sweetalert2.min.css')}}">

    <!-- END: Page CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Custom CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/style.css')}}">
    <!-- END: Custom CSS-->
</head>
```

My form Code

```
 <form class="form form-horizontal" id="formfg"  novalidate>
    <div class="form-body">
                                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="font-weight-bolder">Category Code<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type="text" id="category_code" class="form-control" name="category_code"  value="{{$valuecode}}"  autocomplete="off" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <label class="font-weight-bolder">Category Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <input type="text" id="category_name" class="form-control" name="category_name"  autocomplete="off" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div  class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                    <button type="submit" id="btnData"  class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <a href="{{ url('master-category') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Kembali</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

my js plugin code

```
<!-- BEGIN: Vendor JS-->
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.html5.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/ui/prism.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/forms/validation/jqBootstrapValidation.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme JS-->
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/core/app-menu.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/core/app.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/scripts/components.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/forms/select/select2.full.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('app-assets/sweetalert/sweetalert2.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- END: Theme JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Page JS-->
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/scripts/forms/select/form-select2.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/scripts/forms/validation/form-validation.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- END: Page JS-->
    @yield('script')
```

Comment: Which part of the code would display the message?

Comment: <input type="text" id="category_name" class="form-control" name="category_name"  autocomplete="off" required>

Should show "THIS Field Required" if we don't fill  the textfield and click submit button but in my case noting show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuexy already comes with Vee-validate plugin, if not in your version you can add it explicitly using npm!

After importing, inside your `<form>` for every input or required field you can add a structure like these,

```
<input type="text" 
           id="category_name" 
           class="form-control" 
           name="category_name"  
           autocomplete="off" 
           v-validate="'required'" />
    
    <span class="text-danger text-sm"  
          v-show="errors.has('category_name')">
          
        {{ errors.first('category_name') }}
    </span>
```

Here the  will toggle the errors, look into [vee validate api](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/api/validator.html#validate-api) for further details.